# How to determine the interval for integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-domain

I'm given a double integral. The intervals are not specified, instead are given like this: $x\ge1, y\ge1, 2\le x+y\le3$ I'm stuck at $2\le x+y\le 3$ How to find the values for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Try to sketch the area. Does this help you to find the bounds?

Comment: I think there must be an easier solution. This is for an exam, and we didn't learn solving problems by sketching areas.

Comment: You are supposed to integrate over the set $\{x\ge 1, y\ge 1, x+y\le 3\}$. This is not a square (rather a triangle) so you cannot express it as product of two intervals.

Comment: Easier way would be to divide the area into three triangles and find their areas.

Comment: A picture is fundamental. If you draw it, you will find you are integrating over a triangle, and the solution will write itself.

Comment: No really, @user127.0.0.1's comment is the way to go. If you don't get it, sketch it and all will be clear.

Comment: Sketch the inequalities for this problem as they define the region you are integrating over.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a picture that would help you[image]

Try to find where do the inequalities hold. If it is not clear just let me know

Comment: Very instructive. But why did you draw the line $y=2-x$ too?

Comment: It is just a typo, the problem has just been edited

Comment: @Semsem No, your edit to the question is not even wrong, but there is no need to specify the lower bound of the sum of x and y

Comment: i edited it because he said" I'm stuck at" and write the inequality in its last version @user127.0.0.1

Comment: Thank you. First of all I have no idea what to do with the y. I draw a sketch like the above and highlighted the area where x>=1. I'm sorry for being dumb. I know it's not the way it works with graphs.

Comment: Moreover as you clarified removing this condition will not change the region, you are right @user127.0.0.1